# Python ljust but with multiple characters?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am trying to pad a string with a pattern of two characters in Python.

For example: `"313841444634473732415a2d3347324631"` to `"313841444634473732415a2d334732463120"` or `"ABCD"` to `"ABCD20202020"`

`ljust` takes in a string with a length of just one. Strings with more than one character raise an error:

```
>>> "313841444634473732415a2d3347324631".ljust(36, "20")
TypeError: The fill character must be exactly one character long
```

What should be used in place of `string.ljust(36, "20")` to pad a string with `"20"`?

Comment: I'd still need to adjust the expected size with the size of pad-string. Imagine that `ljust` allows 2 chars and you call `string.ljust("20", 35)`

Comment: Could you use a shorter, clearer example? Padding a 34-digit number with another number is awfully hard to read. The `"ABCD"` example is fine.

Comment: What should happen if the width can't be filled an even number of times by the filler? For example, with `'a'.ljust(4, '12')`, should the result be `'a121'`, `'a122'`, or an error? If you're not sure, I'd go with an error. Alternatively, you could have an argument that specifies the behaviour.

Comment: is it necessary to use ljust() ?

Comment: ... other options are `'a12'` or `'a1212'`, though since they don't match the requested length, they make less sense to me personally.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
mystring = "ABCD"

while len(mystring) < 36:
    mystring += "20"
```

Comment: Just to note, if `mystring = "ABC"`, the final length is 37. OP hasn't said what should happen in cases like that, so I've asked them to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice

def ljust(s1, s2, n):
    return f'{s1}{"".join(islice(cycle(s2), 0, max(0, n-len(s1))))}'

s = "ABCD"
print(ljust(s, "20", 12))
```

Prints:

```
ABCD20202020
```

---

```
s = '313841444634473732415a2d3347324631'
print(ljust(s, "20", 36))
```

Prints:

```
313841444634473732415a2d334732463120
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 Fixed, should be `len(s1)` not `len(s)` :)

Comment: @mkrieger1 For the exception, I've added `max()`

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own string filling function.  Add the repeated filling pattern to your original string (repeating enough to cover the total size) and truncate the resulting concatenation to the specified size.

```
def fill(S,size,filler):
    return (S+filler*size)[:max(size,len(S))]
```

output:

```
print(fill("ABCD",16,"20"))
# ABCD202020202020

print(fill("ABCD",15,"20"))
# ABCD20202020202
```

You could make it more sophisticated by computing the exact number of repetitions and the size of the partial filler to add at the end:

```
def fill(S,size,filler):
    reps,partial = divmod(max(0,size-len(S)),len(filler))
    return S + filler*reps + filler[:partial]
```

*But, unless this is performance critical, the time saving is probably not worth the extra complexity.*